# Create View reverse to DetailView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, detailview, create-view

I am trying to reverse from CreateView to DetailView after I have uploaded my Image.

I get the same message

*NoReverseMatch at /photo/image/add
Reverse for 'image-view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 50}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []*

This is my Model for Image

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from string import join
import os

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name

    def size(self):
            return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)


    def tags_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.tags.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def albums_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.albums.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def thumbnail(self):
        return """<a href="/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" height="40" /></a>""" % (
                                                                        (self.image.name, self.image.name))
        thumbnail.allow_tags = True

    def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('image-view',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from photo import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^image/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ImageView.as_view(),name='image-view',),
    url(r'^$', views.ListImage.as_view(),name ='Photo-List',),
    url(r'^image/add/$', views.ImageCreate.as_view(), name = 'create-image',),
    url(r'update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ImageUpdate.as_view(),name='image-update',),

) 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse
from photo.models import Tag, Image, Album
from django.conf import settings

class ImageView(DetailView):
    model = Image
    allow_empty = True
    template_name = 'image.html'

class ListImage(ListView):
    #context_object_name = 'object_list'
    template_name = 'image_list.html'
    model = Image
    #def get_queryset(self):
    #    return Image.objects.all()

class ImageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Image
    template_name='image_create.html'
    fields = ['title','image']
```

**More details on my error**

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
        return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in post
            return self.form_valid(form) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in form_valid
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in form_valid
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/henriaugris/Documents/Django/mysite/photo/views.py in get_success_url
        return reverse('image-view', kwargs={'pk' : self.object.pk}) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
                             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)) ...
▶ Local vars
Request information

GET
No GET data
```

Comment: Did you try to set success variable on View?

Comment: where is `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` in your models?

Comment: Madzohan: its in my view

Comment: @frlan how to setup success?

Comment: I've already answered - you are using `reverse` in your models `get_absolute_url` but didn't import it there

Answer (score 11):

Instead of setting get_absolute_url in your models.py file as:

```
def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('image-view',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

You could set it in your views.py file under:

```
class ImageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Image
    template_name='image_create.html'
    fields = ['title','image']
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('image-view', kwargs={'pk' : self.object.pk})

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(ImageCreate, self).get_form_kwargs(
            *args, **kwargs)
        return kwargs
```

After making this change, you should delete the get_absolute_url from your models.py file.  With this change, you should land on the detail view of the image you uploaded upon successfully creating a new image.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L156-L169 it is the same

Comment: and what did you mean by override `get_form_kwargs`, but didn't use it?

Comment: I will reupdate my github project tonight, thanks for your patience. I just commented get_form_kwars to debug the first part.

Comment: @madzohan so do you guys have any idea what is wrong? I tried using success_url for my DeletView but it only works when I hardcode the url, so I guess Django does not recognize the names I gave to my different views in urls.py